# Debugger in Rubymine 8.0.3 not working

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubymine

I have "installed" the 7zip [Ruby version 2.2.4](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) as well as the corresponding DevKit. The PATH variable has been set.

When I start the debugging mode in Rubymine 8.0.3 the necessary gems have been installed. But than the following error occurs:

> Error running speed: Cannot start debugger. Gem 'ruby-debug-ide' isn't installed or its executable script 'rdebug-ide' doesn't exist.

When I open the command line (`cmd.exe`) and type `c:\rdebug-ide` then the command line answers correctly

> Using ruby-debug-base 0.2.2.beta6
>   ...

When I call in the command line `gem list` then the gem is listed as `ruby-debug-ide (0.6.0)`.

Do somebody has an idea?

Comment: Looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17799, which was self-resolved. In case your environment differs, could you please add a comment to that issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Personally I deleted Rubymine from Applications and installed again the last version, now it works for me.

Comment: With the new version (2016.1) everything works fine. I really do not understand, what the problem was

Comment: @Dzaic you are lucky it works for you, but in same cases it gets broken, I also don't know why it happens, but when it happens a reinstallation helps. My answer is correct, please remove the minus.

Comment: I dont't know who gave u a minus 1. And i don't know how to remove it.

Comment: @Dzaic, ok sorry. I wish it was you. :)